# Overlapping Window/Page or Custom messagebox?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I want to preface this by saying I'm a noob with WPF/.net programming.

Here is my question that requires a bit of guidance.  I have a window and I load pages in and out as my navigation.  On one particular page, when the user clicks on one of the items (button for example), I need to display a small form to gather more information.  I'm not sure what the best approach is... what I would love (but do not know where to begin even searching for this solution) would be to open a popup balloon style window with a few textboxes and a submit button.

Other options I've explored would be to use a separate page.  Save off the current page and load a new page with these textboxes and a submit button.  Or to use a custom messagebox instead (least favorite option).

I would like this new extra info page to blend in with rest of the app so that the main page is still visible in the background.  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using modal window (ShowDialog) method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF's [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control

```
<Popup>
    <!-- Your Content Here -->
</Popup>
```

Personally I have issues with WPF's Popup, so have [my own custom UserControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) that works like a Popup.